# Simple non-blocking multi-threaded tcp server

Tags: c++, multithreading, tcp, winsock, winsock2

I'm studying C++, and this weekend I started to play around with sockets and threads. Bellow is a simple multi threaded server that I'm making based on some tutorials.

The issue that I'm facing is that when I'm connecting with 2 telnet clients only the keystrokes form the first connection appear on the server. Any keystroke sent from the second telnet connection appears suddenly once the first telnet connection closes. Could someone explain to me what have I done wrong here?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <thread>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>

#pragma comment (lib, "ws2_32.lib")

void clientSocketHandler(SOCKET clientSocket, std::string client_ip) {

    char buf[4096];

    std::thread::id thread_id = std::this_thread::get_id();
    std::cout << thread_id << " - " << client_ip << ": connected" << std::endl;

    while (true)
    {

        ZeroMemory(buf, 4096);

        int bytesReceived = recv(clientSocket, buf, 4096, 0);

        if (bytesReceived == 0)
        {

            std::cout << thread_id << " - " << client_ip << ": disconnected" << std::endl;

            break;

        }

        if (bytesReceived > 0) 
        {

            std::cout << thread_id << " - " << client_ip << ": " << std::string(buf, 0, bytesReceived) << std::endl;

            //send(clientSocket, buf, bytesReceived + 1, 0);

        }

    }

    std::cout << thread_id << " - " << client_ip << ": closing client socket & exiting thread..." << std::endl;

    closesocket(clientSocket);

}

void waitForConnections(SOCKET serverSocket) {

    sockaddr_in hint;

    hint.sin_family = AF_INET;
    hint.sin_port = htons(1337);
    hint.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = INADDR_ANY;

    bind(serverSocket, (sockaddr*)&hint, sizeof(hint));
    listen(serverSocket, SOMAXCONN);

    while (true) {

        sockaddr_in client;

        int clientSize = sizeof(client);

        SOCKET clientSocket = accept(serverSocket, (sockaddr*)&client, &clientSize);

        if (clientSocket != INVALID_SOCKET) 
        {

            char host[NI_MAXHOST];      // Client's remote name

            ZeroMemory(host, NI_MAXHOST); // same as memset(host, 0, NI_MAXHOST);

            std::string client_ip = inet_ntop(AF_INET, &client.sin_addr, host, NI_MAXHOST);
            std::thread t(clientSocketHandler, clientSocket, client_ip);

            t.join();

        }

        Sleep(100);

    }

}

int main()
{
    // Initialze winsock
    WSADATA wsData;
    WORD ver = MAKEWORD(2, 2);

    int wsOk = WSAStartup(ver, &wsData);

    if (wsOk != 0)
    {
        std::cerr << "Can't Initialize winsock! Quitting..." << std::endl;

        return 1;
    }

    // Create a socket
    SOCKET serverSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

    if (serverSocket == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        WSACleanup();
        std::cerr << "Can't create a socket! Quitting..." << std::endl;

        return 1;
    }

    // If serverSocketMode = 0, blocking is enabled; 
    // If serverSocketMode != 0, non-blocking mode is enabled.
    u_long serverSocketMode = 1;

    if (ioctlsocket(serverSocket, FIONBIO, &serverSocketMode) != NO_ERROR) 
    {
        WSACleanup();
        std::cerr << "Can't set socket to non-blocking mode! Quitting..." << std::endl;

        return 1;
    }

    // Disables the Nagle algorithm for send coalescing.
    // This socket option is included for backward 
    // compatibility with Windows Sockets 1.1
    BOOL flag = TRUE;

    if (setsockopt(serverSocket, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_NODELAY, (const char *)&flag, sizeof(flag)) != NO_ERROR)
    {
        WSACleanup();
        std::cerr << "Can't set socket NO_DELAY option! Quitting..." << std::endl;

        return 1;
    }

    // Start listening for connections
    waitForConnections(serverSocket);

    // Cleanup winsock
    WSACleanup();

    system("pause");

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: `t.join();` will wait for the thread to finish before continuing, which AFAICT is the reason your second client input isnt received until first one finishes. That loop wont do a second iteration until the first client is gone. You basically have a single threaded program (you create a thread and then immediately wait for it to finish before doing anything else).

Comment: Oh I see but, If I remove it I get an exception.

Comment: Either have a vector of threads that outlives your loop iterations (and join them later in the program), or call `.detach()`, I'm not sure which makes more sense in your case because yes I believe destroying a thread without calling join/detach does that.

Comment: How do you want to manage the collection of threads you'll have running? Also, you don't handle abnormal termination of the TCP connection. (Maybe you want `if (bytesReceived <= 0)` as a first cut?)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz my first thought was to spawn a thread for each incoming connection and not a specified n length thread-pool. Also regarding `bytesReceived <= 0`, I initially had a check for `bytesReceived == SOCKET_ERROR` which is -1 if I'm not mistaken. and it kept triggering

Comment: There is nothing simple about a nonblocking multithreaded server. If you have nonblocking you don't really need multiple threads, at least for the socket handling part.

Comment: Why are you using the winsock API in a manner that seems explicitly designed to make it hard to port your program to a non-Windows system in the future. I've used that API before, and it's definitely possible to use it mostly like you would use the Berkeley sockets API, which immediately makes your program portable almost anywhere that supports TCP/IP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work. I removed pointless things like setting the socket to non-blocking and disabling the Nagle algorithm. The latter should only be done for things that need low-millisecond interactivity.

But, the substantial change that should fix your problem is changing `join` to `detach`. Using `join` causes your program to wait for the thread to finish before continuing. Using `detach` says "This thread is going to run in the background doing things, and I don't care about learning its fate later.".

If you don't use one of the two, and the `::std::thread` object is destroyed, the system throws an exception because you're destroying the only means you have of getting information about whether or not a thread exited with an error of some kind with saying that either you don't care about such information, or explicitly asking for it.

I don't have Windows, so I can't test it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <thread>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>

#pragma comment (lib, "ws2_32.lib")

void clientSocketHandler(SOCKET clientSocket, std::string client_ip)
{
   char buf[4096];

   std::thread::id thread_id = std::this_thread::get_id();
   std::cout << thread_id << " - " << client_ip << ": connected" << std::endl;

   while (true)
   {

      ZeroMemory(buf, 4096);

      int bytesReceived = recv(clientSocket, buf, 4096, 0);

      if (bytesReceived == 0)
      {

         std::cout << thread_id << " - " << client_ip << ": disconnected" << std::endl;

         break;

      }

      if (bytesReceived > 0)
      {

         std::cout << thread_id << " - " << client_ip << ": " << std::string(buf, 0, bytesReceived) << std::endl;

         //send(clientSocket, buf, bytesReceived + 1, 0);

      }

   }

   std::cout << thread_id << " - " << client_ip << ": closing client socket & exiting thread..." << std::endl;

   closesocket(clientSocket);

}

void waitForConnections(SOCKET serverSocket)
{

   sockaddr_in hint;

   hint.sin_family = AF_INET;
   hint.sin_port = htons(1337);
   hint.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = INADDR_ANY;

   bind(serverSocket, (sockaddr*)&hint, sizeof(hint));
   listen(serverSocket, SOMAXCONN);

   while (true) {

      sockaddr_in client;

      int clientSize = sizeof(client);

      SOCKET clientSocket = accept(serverSocket, (sockaddr*)&client, &clientSize);

      if (clientSocket != INVALID_SOCKET)
      {

         char host[NI_MAXHOST];      // Client's remote name

         ZeroMemory(host, NI_MAXHOST); // same as memset(host, 0, NI_MAXHOST);

         std::string client_ip = inet_ntop(AF_INET, &client.sin_addr, host, NI_MAXHOST);
         std::thread t(clientSocketHandler, clientSocket, client_ip);

         t.detach();

      }

      Sleep(100);

   }

}

int main()
{
    // Initialze winsock
    WSADATA wsData;
    WORD ver = MAKEWORD(2, 2);

    int wsOk = WSAStartup(ver, &wsData);

    if (wsOk != 0)
    {
        std::cerr << "Can't Initialize winsock! Quitting..." << std::endl;

        return 1;
    }

    // Create a socket
    SOCKET serverSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

    if (serverSocket == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        WSACleanup();
        std::cerr << "Can't create a socket! Quitting..." << std::endl;

        return 1;
    }

    // Start listening for connections
    waitForConnections(serverSocket);

    // Cleanup winsock
    WSACleanup();

    system("pause");

    return 0;

}
```